# Failed Predicate Exception

Tags: exception, antlr4, ambiguous-grammar

Can anyone give me some examples of Failed Predicate exception in ANTLR.

and some examples that will clearly explain :- **input mismatch** VS **failed predicate** VS **no viable alt exceptions** in ANTLR. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The names of the exceptions pretty much explain when they can appear. Only the failed predicate exception is a bit special.

`NoViableAlt`:

Thrown when you try to match block with several alternatives and none matches. Example:

```
r: 'a' | 'b';
```

Input: 'c'.

`InputMismatch`:

Thrown when you have input that partially matches. Example:

```
r: 'a' 'b' 'c' EOF;
```

Input: 'a' 'b' or 'a' 'c' EOF.

`FailedPredicateException`:

Thrown in certain situations where a path is guarded by a predicate and this path is the only possible match (or a required match), but the predicate prevents matching it. For example:

```
... | a ({condition}? b)
```

However if the block with the predicate is optional (so it's not required) then no predicate exception is thrown, like with:

```
... | a ({condition}? b)?
```

For more advanced use of these exceptions for generating better error messages see [this error listener](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-shell-plugins/blob/master/gui/frontend/src/parsing/mysql/MySQLErrorListener.ts#L227).